# Fast Monte-Carlo simulation with numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm following the exercises from "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" in both R and Python.

I would like to find a **fast method of doing Monte-Carlo simulation that uses constant space**.

The problem below is trivial, but serves as a good test for different methods:

> ex 4.3
>
> Determine the exact probability of drawing a 10 from a shuffled pinochle deck. (In a pinochle deck, there are 48 cards. There are six values: 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace. There are two copies of each value in each of the standard four suits: hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades.)
>
> (A) What is the probability of getting a 10?

Of course, the answer is 1/6.

The fastest solution I could find (comparable to the speed of R) is generating a large array of card draws using `np.random.choice`, then applying a `Counter`. I don't like the idea of creating arrays unnecessarily, so I tried using a dictionary and a for loop, drawing one card at a time and incrementing the count for that type of card. To my surprise, it was much slower!

The full code is below for the 3 methods I tested. _Is there a way of doing this that will be as performant as method1(), but using **constant space?**

**Python code:** ([Google Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16B155Zr6CZPXu64cBlqQQ7RXkTB4f_y6))

```py
deck = [c for c in ['9','10','Jack','Queen','King','Ace'] for _ in range(8)]
num_draws = 1000000

def method1():
  draws = np.random.choice(deck, size=num_draws, replace=True)
  df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(draws)])/num_draws
  print(df)
  
def method2():
  card_counts = defaultdict(int)
  for _ in range(num_draws):
    card_counts[np.random.choice(deck, replace=True)] += 1
  df = pd.DataFrame([card_counts])/num_draws
  print(df)
  
def method3():
  card_counts = defaultdict(int)
  for _ in range(num_draws):
    card_counts[deck[random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)]] += 1
  df = pd.DataFrame([card_counts])/num_draws
  print(df)
```

**Python timeit() results:**

method1: 1.2997

method2: 23.0626

method3: 5.5859

**R code:**

```
card = sample(deck, numDraws, replace=TRUE)
print(as.data.frame(table(card)/numDraws))
```

Comment: What was the sample `deck` and `num_draws` used for the timing?

Comment: Updated question with info:
```deck = [c for c in ['9','10','Jack','Queen','King','Ace'] for _ in range(8)]
num_draws = 1000000```

Comment: You could make your deck have 0s and 1s in it and then sum the values drawn.  Does that count?

Comment: @DavisHerring Could you explain that further?

Comment: Making large arrays in `numpy` is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @JulesKuehn: Instead of making a list of strings, make a list of numbers that indicate how many cards you just drew were 10s.  (Most of those numbers are 0 and the remaining few are 1, of course.)  Then sum and divide by the number of draws.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)+[`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
def unique():    
    unq,ids = np.unique(deck, return_inverse=True)
    all_ids = np.random.choice(ids, size=num_draws, replace=True)
    ar = np.bincount(all_ids)/num_draws
    return pd.DataFrame(ar[None], columns=unq)
```

#### How does NumPy help here?

There are two major improvements that's helping us here :

1. We convert the string data to numeric. NumPy works well with such data. To achieve this, we are using `np.unique`.
2. We use `np.bincount` to replace the counting step. Again, it works well with numeric data and we do have that from the numeric conversion done at the start of this method.
3. NumPy in general works well with large data, which is the case here.

---

Timings with given sample dataset comparing against fastest `method1` -

```
In [177]: %timeit method1()
328 ms ± 16.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [178]: %timeit unique()
12.4 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Amazing speedup by taking the strings / Counter out of the equation! This still uses O(num_draws) space though. Any way around this?

Comment: @JulesKuehn Are you worried about the memory complexity or the computational complexity?

Comment: My question states that I'm looking for a O(1) space solution. I suppose your solution could be adapted to put a bound on the space, at the expense of having to run the first 3 lines multiple times.

Comment: @JulesKuehn When you talk about "space", are you talking about memory space or something else? If you are worried about memory space, creating `all_ids` could be an issue. If you are worried about runtime/performance efficiency, then you would have to understand how NumPy gains performance. It is through temporal and spatial locality of array data. `all_ids` is the array in context. So, there's always a trade-off between memory and performance. But, your concept of "space" isn't clear to me.

Comment: Yes - I meant the memory used by the array created by np.random.choice. I was looking for a solution that used a generator / loop / etc, so that memory (space) would remain constant regardless of the number of samples.

Comment: @JulesKuehn And you don't care about performance? I thought that was main concern of this post. If you care about both memory stick to your loop-based ones. If you care about performance, go with this one.

Comment: You can create a tradeoff by dividing the draws into fixed chunks. That way you should use constant memory: the counters and the buffer for drawing. You will still slow down a bit for the outer, chunk loop (in Python), but will still have some speedup for the inner, draw loop.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy achieves efficiency by running C code in its numerical engine. Python is convenient, but it is orders of magnitude slower than C.

In Numpy and other high-performance Python libraries, the Python code consists mostly of glue code, preparing the task to be dispatched. Since there is overhead, it is much faster to draw a lot of samples at once.

Remember that providing a buffer of 1 million elements for Numpy to work is still constant space. Then you can sample 1 billion times by looping it.

This extra memory allocation is usually not a problem. If you must avoid using memory at all costs while still getting performance benefits from Numpy, you can try using Numba or Cython to accelerate it.

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def method4():
    card_counts = np.zeros(6)
    for _ in range(num_draws):
        card_counts[np.random.randint(0, 6)] += 1
    return card_counts/num_draws
```